# Sometimes, when I press Alt-F4, a stream of "p"s is generated

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, input

Sometimes, when I press Alt-F4 to close a program or window, the computer starts acting as if I'm holding down the P key, which creates lag and hijacks whatever text field is in focus.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?